# Java Gson byte[] array getting converted into ArrayList

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson, deserialization

I am using Gson for object serialization and deserialization but **Gson converts byte[] array to ArrayList**

Object class

```
public class RequesterArgument implements Serializable {

 private Object data;
 
     public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
    
}
```

And I have an object array[]

```
byte[] data = {74,97,118,97,73,110,85,115,101};
```

now i am setting this byte[] to my object

```
    byte[] data = {74,97,118,97,73,110,85,115,101};
    
    RequesterArgument request = new RequesterArgument();
    request.setData(data);

System.out.println(request.getData().getClass().getName());
```

now the output is **[B** byte

but if I convert it to a JSON string

```
String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(request);
```

and again try to convert it to the Actual object

```
RequesterArgument response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, RequesterArgument.class);

System.out.println(response.getData().getClass().getName());
```

and if I try to print the class name not it is giving me the **java.util.ArrayList** type

So is there any way to avoid type conversion without changing the actual type?
**Note:  **(if I change Object data to a byte[] data then it is working fine)****

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is there any way to avoid type conversion

No, at least not with your current code. Gson serializes Java arrays as JSON arrays. On deserialization Gson only knows that the field type is `Object` and recognizes that the JSON data contains a JSON array consisting of JSON numbers. In that case it deserializes the data as `List<Double>` (or more specifically `ArrayList<Double>`).

The cleanest solution might be to add a type parameter to `RequesterArgument`, representing the type of `data`:

```java
public class RequesterArgument<T> {
    private T data;

    ...
}
```

The main difference is that when you now use `Gson.fromJson`, you have to provide a `TypeToken` which specifies the actual argument for `T` (see also the [User Guide](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#serializing-and-deserializing-generic-types)):

```java
TypeToken<RequesterArgument<byte[]>> typeToken = new TypeToken<RequesterArgument<byte[]>>() {};

RequesterArgument<byte[]> response = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, typeToken);
```

(Note: Older Gson versions require that you call `typeToken.getType()`)

If that solution is not possible for you, another option would be to add a [`@JsonAdapter`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/annotations/JsonAdapter.html) annotation to the field, which refers to a custom [`TypeAdapterFactory`](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.google.code.gson/gson/latest/com.google.gson/com/google/gson/TypeAdapterFactory.html) whose adapter peeks at the JSON data and then depending on the type tries to deserialize it as `byte[]`.

Also, as side note Gson does not require that your classes implement `Serializable`. And also to avoid any misunderstandings, Gson does not use getters and setters, it directly modifies the field value. Though you can of course let your own code call the getters and setters.

Comment: thanks for the details information, let me try with solution that you provided. thank you once again.